# Error: Index was out of range when updating multiple rows in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to update multiple rows on a gridview using a single button click, however after the update as completed on the first 10 times it throw this error message Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index. I have a page count and page indexing on the gridview but it's not moving to the next page to complete the update.

```
 protected void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB);

        string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; //Gets current User.
       

        int a = 0;

       

        #region Update Barcode 

        DataTable TableP = (DataTable)ViewState["Product"];

        for (int i = 0; i < TableP.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label barcode = (Label)Product.Rows[a].Cells[0].FindControl("Barcode");
            Label barcodeLocation = (Label)Product.Rows[a].Cells[1].FindControl("barcodeLocation");
            Label batchID = (Label)Product.Rows[a].Cells[4].FindControl("batchID");
            Label upc = (Label)Product.Rows[a].Cells[5].FindControl("UPC");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateBarcode", con);

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeNo", barcode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastupdate", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", batchID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeLocation", barcodeLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPC", upc.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            a++;
        }


        GetBarcodeDetails();

        #endregion

       



    }
```

Comment: You want to update a complete dataset on a paged gridview instead of the current page?

Comment: Why do you have both ````i```` and ````a```` variables?  Just use the ````i```` only.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran, yes that's what I would like to do

Comment: Have you enabled paging on your `GridView`?

Comment: yes I did allowpaging to be true

Comment: @JohnPete22,  that gave me the same error message

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, You want to update all of the rows present in a datatable row while you do not have those rows bound to the `GridView` Control, which means you cannot update more than the rows that you have bound to the `GridView`.

For that, you will have to either bind all the rows by disabling paging (Which is not recommended if you have many records), or you should manually update your `DataSource` which in case is your `DataTable` object. You modify it then bind it to the `GridView`.

You need to loop through the only bound elements as I see you are getting the values from the gridview columns. This will update only the bound rows but won't cause an exception as it loops through only the indexes that are bound to `GridView`

change your loop to go through the bound rows only:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // your code.
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you read closely, I suggested you update your gridview to support all the rows in order to get it working. Remove paging.

Comment: I did remove paging